# Listar itens de um dropbox com navbar responsivo bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, nav-bar

Estou formulando uma página responsiva com bootstrap, onde tenho 2 barras:

- NAVBAR onde possuo a logo da empresa, e um simples dropbox com o nome da pessoa, e com as opções alterar senha e sair.
- MAINBAR onde tem o menu de navegação do site.

Quando acessado por um dispositivo movel, ele muda a vizualização para o padrão bootstrap, onde possui um simples botão por barra que quando clicado abre o menu correspondente em forma de lista.

Quando clica no NAVBAR pelo dispositivo, ele abre um menu escrito o nome da pessoa e em seguida tenho que clicar no nome da pessoa para abrir o menu de alterar senha e sair.

Gostaria de saber se tem como tirar esse clique a mais no nome da pessoa e ir direto para as opções alterar senha e sair, ou já exibir expandido quando clicado no botão do menu NAVBAR.

Este é o código:

```html
<div class="navbar">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-image" href="http://www.example.com.br">
        <img src="logo.png">
      </a>

    </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="dropdown navbar-profile">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">
            <span class="navbar-profile-label">NOME DO USUARIO</span>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

            <li>
              <a href="profile.php">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
                Perfil
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="profilePassword.php">
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> 
                Alterar Senha
              </a>
            </li>

            <li class="divider"></li>

            <li>
              <a href="logout.php">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> 
                Sair
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div> <!--/.navbar-collapse -->

  </div> <!-- /.container -->

</div> <!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="mainbar">

  <div class="container">

    <button type="button" class="btn mainbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mainbar-collapse">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="mainbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainbar-nav">
        
<!--

        CRIAÇÃO DO MENU DE NAVEGAÇÃO DO SITE, EXEMPLO DE OPÇÂO:

        <li class="MENU ATIVO OU NÃO ATIVO">
          <a href="index.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
            Dashboard
          </a>
        </li>
        
-->
      </ul>

    </div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->   

  </div> <!-- /.container --> 

</div> <!-- /.mainbar -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isto é bem simples, basta verificar qual é a resolução do dispositivo móvel e adicionar a classe `open` dentro da classe dropdown ficando assim:

```
<li class="dropdown open">
```

Acredito que não seja tão UX esta pratica por isto segue um exemplo de como eu implementaria:

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Logo" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Usuário <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Perfil</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Alterar Senha</a>
          </li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sair</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Removi o `data-toggle="dropdown"` e adicionei para abrir o menu no hover.

Answer (score 0):

E se você tirasse a primeira lista `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"/>` e colocasse o nome do usuário no topo da segunda. Ficando como abaixo:

```html
<div class="navbar">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-image" href="http://www.example.com.br">
        <img src="logo.png">
      </a>

    </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">


          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">
            <span class="navbar-profile-label">NOME DO USUARIO</span>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </a>

            <li>
              <a href="profile.php">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
                Perfil
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="profilePassword.php">
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> 
                Alterar Senha
              </a>
            </li>

            <li class="divider"></li>

            <li>
              <a href="logout.php">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> 
                Sair
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>

    </div> <!--/.navbar-collapse -->

  </div> <!-- /.container -->

</div> <!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="mainbar">

  <div class="container">

    <button type="button" class="btn mainbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mainbar-collapse">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="mainbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainbar-nav">
        
<!--

        CRIAÇÃO DO MENU DE NAVEGAÇÃO DO SITE, EXEMPLO DE OPÇÂO:

        <li class="MENU ATIVO OU NÃO ATIVO">
          <a href="index.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
            Dashboard
          </a>
        </li>
        
-->
      </ul>

    </div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->   

  </div> <!-- /.container --> 

</div> <!-- /.mainbar -->
```